# How to overwrite types from a module in Typescript + React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am currently using React integrated with Typescript, and more often than not I come across the following problem:

- I download a module from npm
- I download the types from that module
- Some types are wrong and I get typescript errors trying to follow the documentation

Is there some way to overwrite the types definition of a module without messing around inside node_modules?

Comment: It depends on the package. For example, if the types for a given package reference the types for another package it will be difficult to override them. Given that you said you would encounter this problem "more often than not", I would venture to guess that you may be either misunderstanding or misconfiguring something.

Comment: Maybe I overstated the frequency. Supposing the types does not reference any other types, what could I do?

Comment: There are a few ways. You can create your own declaration file, named exactly as the package it types, place it in a directory like `/custom_types`, and then customize `"typeRoots"` to `["custom_types", "node_modules/@types"], so the language includes that location when it searches for types, and then uninstall the problematic `@types` package. You can also use `"paths`"